# Как составить функцию, чтоб число f, встало на позицию h

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a[100], n, b, g, f,h;
    printf(" Введите размер массива ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
      printf(" Введите диапазон:  ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &g);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i< n; i++)
{
        a[i] = rand() % g + b;
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
      printf(" Укажите еще один элемент:  ");
    scanf("%d", &f);
      printf(" \nПозиция в массиве:  ");
    scanf("%d", &h);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот что я придумал, надеюсь это вам поможет.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i, a[100], n, b, g, f, h;
    printf("Введите размер массива ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
     printf("Введите диапазон:  ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &g);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i< n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % g + b;
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf(" \nУкажите еще один элемент:  ");
    scanf("%d", &f);
    printf(" \nПозиция в массиве:  ");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    
    for(i=n; i>= h; i--){
        a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    a[h-1] = f;
    n++;
    for(i=0; i< n; i++){
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)
Выручили